# ElementClickInterceptedException Error won't fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Ok this is a bit embarrassing because I've asked a similar question on here sometime ago, but I tried the suggested solution ie (wait till element clickable), but it didn't work. So here's my code snipped.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException, ElementNotInteractableException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
import re
import pandas as pd


def get_links(link):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    sleep(5)

    _flag = True
    knt = 0
    while _flag:
        try:
        
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(class='ot-buttons-fw')]")))
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']")))
        
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Show more matches')]").click()
            print("works here!")
            print("clicked....................................")
            sleep(5)
            _flag = True
            #tmp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'NBA - Pre-season')]")
            #if len(tmp) > 0:
                #print("Found them!")
                #_flag = False
            if knt > 5: # For testing
                print("Nuff clicked")
                _flag = False
        except(ElementNotInteractableException):
            print("Error!")
            _flag = False
        
    driver.close()
    return None

link = "https://www.flashscore.com/basketball/usa/nba/results/"

_ = get_links(link)
```

For some reason I keep getting an `ElementClickInterceptedException` Error at the `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Show more matches')]").click()` line. Any help can do please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element overlap with other element, it cause the `ElementClickInterceptedException` error appear.

Before perform you code, please close the cookies popup with this code snippet:

```
def get_links(link):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    sleep(5)

    #here, close popup
    if(len(driver.find_elements_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))>0):
        driver.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()

    _flag = True
    knt = 0
    while _flag:
        ....
        ....
```

And remove this line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(class='ot-buttons-fw')]")))
```

This is invalid xpath expression, and no needed, have handled by `if(popup accept)` condition the above.